# Solve the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-5\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=10\cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-5\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=10\cos x$$

with $y=\dfrac{dy}{dx}\:=0$ when $x=0$

My question is should I use Auxiliary Equation, and if yes, should be like this:

$k^2-5k+6=0$

or

$k^2-5k+6=10\cos\left(x\right)$ ?

Comment: First solve the homogeneous differential equation using the auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

Our differential equation is:

$$y'' - 5y' + 6y = 10\cos x$$

Constructing the characteristic polynomial:

$$r^2 - 5r + 6 = 0,\ (r-3)(r-2) = 0$$

Therefore our characteristic equation is:

$$y_c(x) = c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{3x}$$

Next, we find the particular solution:

We know it follows the format

$$y_p(x) = A\cos x + B\sin x$$

Since the right-hand side is $10\cos x$

$${y_p}'(x) = -A\sin x + B\cos x$$

$${y_p}''(x)= -A\cos x -B\sin x$$

Putting this into our differential equation:

$$-A\cos x -B\sin x - 5(-A\sin x + B\cos x) + 6(A\cos x + B\sin x) = 10\cos x$$

Combining, we get:

$$-A\cos x -B\sin x + 5A\sin x - 5B\cos x + 6A\cos x + 6B\sin x = 10\cos x$$

$$\cos x (-A + 6A -5B) + \sin x(-B + 5A + 6B) = 10\cos x$$

Therefore we have,

$$5A - 5B = 10$$

and

$$5A +5B = 0$$

Therefore, $A = 1$ and $B = -1$

So $y_p(x) = \cos x - \sin x$

Therefore our solution is: $$y(x) = c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{3x} + \cos x - \sin x$$

If $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 0$

$$y(0) = c_1 + c_2 + 1 = 0$$

$$y'(x) = 2c_1e^{2x} + 3c_2e^{3x} - \sin x - \cos x$$

$$y'(0) = 2c_1 + 3c_2 - 1 = 0$$
Solving, we get $c_1 = -4$ and $c_2 = 3$

Our final solution is:

$$y(x) = -4e^{2x} + 3e^{3x} + \cos x - \sin x$$

Comment: I didn't understand this part of the answer, We know it follows the format

$$y_p(x) = A\cos x + B\sin x$$

Since the right-hand side is $10\cos x$

$${y_p}'(x) = -A\sin x + B\cos x$$

$${y_p}''(x)= -A\cos x -B\sin x$$

Comment: We are using the method of undetermined coefficients to find our particular solution. We guess the particular solution by using the type of function on the right-hand side. Since it is of the form $\cos x$, it is a trigonometric function and our guess is: $A\cos x + B\sin x$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The auxiliary equation is to help you find the homogeneous solution (complementary solution). You'll have to find the particular integral corresponding to $10\cos(x)$ separately.